# Problem in proof of alternating series test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

The proof from Lamar math website is linked http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx and can be found at the bottom of that page.

Shouldn’t $S_2=-b_1+b_2$ ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.  Their proof would be more readable with sign $(-1)^{n+1}$ so that the series starts off positive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was thinking about it and I suppose it is irrelevant since the conclusions are the same if there is $(-1)^(n+1) or (-1)^n$it’s just good to know I’m not going crazy! :)

Comment: It's irrelevant but annoying.